# DOM select works, jquery doesn't

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a new feature for our website and want to start using jquery to modernize our javascript. I'm having some issues selecting  elements in a table. My issue is that the legacy way we do this works, but the jquery way doesn't seem to work. I realize everyone is going to immediately ask for HTML but extracting that will take some time to remove a lot of the junk that isn't relevant. At the moment I'm just wondering if I'm screwing up the syntax. Syntactically, is this correct? I am using jquery 1.9.1.

```
// no messages :-(
$('censusGrid').find('select').each(function () { alert($(this)); });

// messages :-)
var elements = document.getElementById('censusGrid').getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    alert(elements[i]);
}
```

Comment: you missed the `#` Think of jQuery selectors like CSS selectors (because in most cases they are)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jQuery selector is incorrect. If you want to find stuff by ID, you use the css # selector, if you want to find stuff by class name, you use the css . selector. your jQuery selector should look like this:

```
$('#censusGrid').find('select')...
```

Comment: Embarrassing mistake. But thanks everyone for the clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

Almost, it seems `censusGrid` is an ID, so it should be:

```
$('#censusGrid').find('select').each(function () { alert($(this)); });
```

Basically you're missing the `#` to indicate your selector is an ID, without it, it'd indicate the name of the tag...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `#` in your jquery:

```
$('#censusGrid').etc...
```

`#` tells jquery it's an ID:

```
$('#selector') - finds <td id="selector">
$('selector') - finds <selector>
$('.selector') - finds <td class="selector">
```